# Downsize Azure Linux VM to save cost

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I would reduce my OS disk ( Linux : CentOS) from 128 Gb to 64Gb to save cost.

when i go to portal and resize : a error message is showing :

```
Failed to update disk 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'. Error: The disk/snapshot resource with id hayppyness-preprod/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX cannot be resized down. Reducing disk/snapshot size is not supported in Azure to prevent data loss. If you do need to reduce the size of the disk, please create new snapshot/disks with the appropriate size. More information is available at https://aka.ms/AzureDisksFAQ.
```

but no information provided by the link.

I can't open a support request because my support plan if Free.

Can someone can help me please ?

Comment: Is it a standard disk or a premium disk?

Comment: Premium SSD LRS

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Comment: i'am so busy but i will check the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, we cannot directly shrink or downsize the azure managed disks. Azure does not support the operation. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/faq-for-disks#managed-disks).
[image]

If we want to downsize the azure disk. We need to export the disk as vhd then shrink the exported VHD. At last, create a new managed disk from the VHD and create a new VM from the new managed disk. For more details, please refer to [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/how-to-shrink-a-managed-disk/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/280428/powershell-script-to-reduce-os-disk-size-in-azure.html)

Comment: I was able to create disk as per the link provided. When i tried to mount the disk i am getting this error - mount: /datadrive: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'. Any inputs to resolve this issue.